# Slim PHP separate function

Tags: php, slim

im having problem understanding Slim PHP, by the way i'm new on this framework.
This first line of code works.

```
$app->post('/book',  function() use ($app){

   $app->response();

  /****  Some code here  ***/
});
```

but i want so separate the function so I try so make it like this

```
$app->post('/book', 'addBook');

function addBook() {

  $app->response();

  /*** Some code here  ***/
}
```

but the code above doesn't work.
What i'm missing guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the getInstance():

```
$app->post('/book', 'addBook');

function addBook() {

    $app = Slim::getInstance();

    $app->response();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semicolon after

```
  $app->response();
                  ^
```

You also won't be able to reference `$app` in that function. That notation is only available for [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). You could do something like this:

```
$app->get('/book/', function () use ($app) { addBook($app); } );

function addBook($app) {

  var_dump($app->response());

  /*** Some code here  ***/
};
```

Comment: sorry for that.. it has semicolon